# Insert a view dynamically in a HorizontalScrollView in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, horizontalscrollview

I'm developing an application for Android tablet 3.0 that has one activity that should be scrollable in the horizontal axis, like an e-book.

For that, I'm using a RelativeLayout inside a HorizontalScrollView on my layout. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="800px"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
    android:background="#C6D7D2" android:layout_height="600px">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">        
    </RelativeLayout>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This xml file is called main.xml.

What I'm doing in the java file is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
View v = createView(); // Thats working for sure.
parent.addView(v);
```

But it is not working, the view V doesn't show on the screen. But if i do

```
addContentView(v)
```

it adds the view v to the screen (the proof that my method works), but it isn't scrollable since it is outside the HorizontalScrollView. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I tried with that and it also didn't work out:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
View v = new View(this);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
parent.addView(v,params);
```

I don't get a blue background.

Comment: Have you tried changing your RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation?

Comment: Why don't you get your container as `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Are you sure you setting the right layoutparams and height width to that view.? Need to see your `createView()` method.

Comment: @user7777777777 the view that i create is actually a class that extends View. And i try doing parent.addView(v,params); where params is a LayoutParams which contain height and width set to wrap_content. So i just instantiate one object of the type view, and then when I add it to the parent i set the parameters

Comment: In your update, There is nothing in your view 'v' thats why it wont show up. Set some height and width instead of `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Comment: How about make
parent.addView(v,params); before setContentView(R.layout.main); Or at least parent.invalidate() after adding view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the width of Relativelayout to `wrap_content`.

Try using this method to add the view.

```
void addView (View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
```

EDIT:

Remove `android:orientation="horizontal"` from the `HorizontalScrollView`

Comment: Already tried, didn't worked either.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: the removal of the orientation also didn't work. Thank you for your help. You can also check out the update i did on the question.

Comment: The problem was that the height and widht of the LayoutParams had to be something diferent than wrap_content or fill_parent. Dont know why but that solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: The reason may be that the view was empty. It did not have any content... like text or image etc.. so wrapping content was making the view's size as zero.

Answer (score 23):

```
HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

        LinearLayout topLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
       // topLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        topLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){



            final ImageView imageView = new ImageView (this);

            imageView.setTag(i);

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            topLinearLayout.addView(imageView);

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("Tag",""+imageView.getTag());
                }
            });


        }

        scrollView.addView(topLinearLayout);


//      ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
//      final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
//      
//      
//      
//      ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
//      .threadPoolSize(3)
//      .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
//      .memoryCacheSize(1500000) // 1.5 Mb
//      .discCacheSize(50000000) // 50 Mb
//      .httpReadTimeout(10000) // 10 s
//      .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
//      .enableLogging() // Not necessary in common
//      .build();
//  // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
//  ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
//      
//      final DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
//      .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
//      .cacheInMemory()
//      .cacheOnDisc()
//      .build();
//      
//      imageLoader.displayImage("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_Sd45ASngYHA/TVC78RORKoI/AAAAAAAAARk/y0GcNkTmb40/s1600/android+logo1.jpg",img,options);
//      
//      img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
//      {
//          
//          @Overridt
//          public void onClick(View v)
//          {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              Dialog d =new Dialog(TestActivity.this);
//              d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
//          
//              d.setCancelable(true);
//              
//              ImageView d_img=(ImageView)d.findViewById(R.id.dialog_img);
////                d.setLayoutParams(L)
//              imageLoader.displayImage("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_Sd45ASngYHA/TVC78RORKoI/AAAAAAAAARk/y0GcNkTmb40/s1600/android+logo1.jpg",d_img,options);
//              
//              d.show();
//              }
//      });
```

Answer (score 1):

you add the view into the relativelayout not into the horizontalscrollview using parent

try with the horizontalscrollview object as you can done with the relativelayout

Comment: I can't add it to the horizontalscrollview, because the horizontalscrollview can only have one child, which is the layout

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code.

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.blue);


parent.addView(v,params);
```