# how to add dynamic image with horizontal scrollview/listview

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have to develop `five to six` `horizontal` scrolling `view`,in this scrolling `image` add dynamic using `adapter`.

**Feature:**
1) Image can be drag and drop one scroll view to another

2) image can be move one horizontal scrolling to another view

3) image can be selected/unselected

4) with with all version

i am using this [**library**](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34), but sometime scrolling is not that much smooth(chopping)

Answer (score 1):

Check this links may be it's useful to you.
1) [Insert a view dynamically in a HorizontalScrollView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186040/insert-a-view-dynamically-in-a-horizontalscrollview-in-android)
2) http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html
3) [Horizontal ListView like Google Catalogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420339/horizontal-listview-like-google-catalogs)

Comment: thanks for giving quick reply.second and third is not useful for me,i am trying first one.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can add android control programatically to linear layout and just add Horizontal Scrollview to Linear Layout through xml
You will get horizontally listview.

```
//My coding here.
String[] name={"PRASHANT","PRASHANT","PRASHANT","PRASHANT","PRASHANT","PRASHANT","PRASHANT"} ;

myLInearLayoutmain =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutmain);



for(int i =0;i<6;i++)
{
    LinearLayout li=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    li.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsnew = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


    params1.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);
    //add textView
    valueTV = new TextView(this);
    valueTV.setText(""+name[i]);
    valueTV.setId(5);
    valueTV.setLayoutParams(paramsnew);
    valueTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    // adding Button to linear
    valueB = new Button(this);
    valueB.setText(""+name[i]);
    valueB.setId(i);
    valueB.setLayoutParams(params);
    valueB.setOnClickListener(this);
    valueB.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    // adding Imageto linear
    img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    img.setLayoutParams(paramsnew);


    //add the textView and the Button to LinearLayout
    li.addView(valueTV);
    li.addView(valueB);
    li.addView(img);

    li.setLayoutParams(params1);
    myLInearLayoutmain.addView(li);
}
```